# EditText inside ListView Crash onItemClick from row 11

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-edittext, android-checkbox

I have an `EditText` and `Checkbox` inside the `ListView` of 20 rows. `EditText` is hidden for first 7 rows and then Visible for all other rows. `CheckBox` is Visible for first 7 rows and then Hidden for other rows. `onItemClick` I have given the `toast` to get text of the `Edittext` which works fine for starting 10 rows but not for the last rows which comes on the scrolling.The App gets crash giving the `NullPointerException` Error

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){ 

        /********** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null); 

        /******** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ************/
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        holder.check =(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
         holder.text2=(EditText)vi.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

       /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);


        j++;

        if(j<8){
       holder.text2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       holder.check.setX(-150);
        }else
        {
             holder.check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }



    }
    else  
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    holder.text2.getText();
       if(data.size()<=0)
    {
        holder.text.setText("No Data");

        holder.text2.getText();
 //        Log.v("BBBB",  holder.text2.getText().toString());

    }
    else
    {
        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        tempValues=null;
        tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);

        /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
         holder.text.setText(tempValues.getCompanyName());

         holder.text2.getText();
                         /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
         vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    }

    Log.v("DDD",  holder.text2.getText().toString());
    return vi;
}
```

and

```
 @Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}


 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position; 
}
```

But the app crash onITemClick method...Even EditText text gets the cause of error..

```
  public void onItemClick(int mPosition)
{


     View vListSortOrder;
     vListSortOrder=list.getChildAt(mPosition);     
     Log.d("valueeeeeeee", Integer.toString(mPosition));

     EditText edit=(EditText)vListSortOrder.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   String temp=edit.getText().toString();
}


public void onClick(View arg0) { 
CustomListViewAndroidExample sct = (CustomListViewAndroidExample)activity; sct.onItemClick(mPosition); }
```

The above onItemClick works fine for starting 10 rows .. but on 11th row it gets crash on `EditText edit` line with null pointer exception error

logcat

```
04-28 00:46:29.101: W/dalvikvm(2178): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
04-28 00:46:29.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2178): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 00:46:29.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2178): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 00:46:29.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2178):     at com.androidexample.customlistview.CustomListViewAndroidExample.onItemClick(CustomListViewAndroidExample.java:172)
04-28 00:46:29.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2178):     at com.androidexample.customlistview.CustomAdapter$OnItemClickListener.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:222)
```

**complete adapter code**

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi") public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter   implements OnClickListener {

/*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
 private Activity activity;
 private ArrayList data;
 private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
 public Resources res;
 ListModel tempValues=null;
 int i=0;

int j=0;

public ArrayList<String> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();


/*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d,Resources resLocal) {

    /********** Take passed values **********/
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    res = resLocal;

    /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () **********************/
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

/******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
public int getCount() {

    if(data.size()<=0)
        return 1;
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

/********* Create a holder to contain inflated xml file elements ***********/
public static class ViewHolder{

    public TextView text;
    public TextView text1;
    public EditText text2;
    public TextView textWide;
    public ImageView image;
    public CheckBox check;

}

/*********** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row ***********/
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    View vi=convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){ 

        /********** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null); 

        /******** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ************/
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        holder.check =(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                holder.text2=(EditText)vi.findViewById(R.id.editText1);



       holder.check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

           @Override
             public void onClick(View v) 
             {
                 if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) 
                 {
                     holder.text2.setText("Checked");


                 }
                 else
                 {
                     holder.text2.setText("Not Checked");

                 }
             }
        });



       /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);



        j++;

        if(j<8){
       holder.text2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       holder.check.setX(-150);
       holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }else
        {
             holder.check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             holder.text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }



    }
    else  
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    holder.text2.getText();
      if(data.size()<=0)
    {
        holder.text.setText("No Data");

        holder.text2.getText();

    }
    else
    {
        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        tempValues=null;
        tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);

        /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
         holder.text.setText(tempValues.getCompanyName());

         /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
         vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    }



    return vi;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position; 
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v("CustomAdapter", "=====Row button clicked");
}

/********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{           
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position){
         mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        CustomListViewAndroidExample sct = (CustomListViewAndroidExample)activity;
        sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
    }               
}
```

}

```
04-28 03:33:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(4917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 03:33:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(4917): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 03:33:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at com.androidexample.customlistview.CustomListViewAndroidExample$1.onClick(CustomListViewAndroidExample.java:89)
04-28 03:33:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
04-28 03:33:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
04-28 03:33:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
```

Comment: please post logcat error

Comment: Please format your code correctly. It is very confusing to read.

Comment: Please read my answer and try to answer the question I have asked you there, so that I could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have write confusing code.

you insert tag to text2 on:

```
holder.text2.setTag(1);
```

then next line of that use:

```
int position12 = (Integer)holder.text2.getTag();
```

so every time `position12` is equal to 1.

next thing is using of `j`instead of position.

you need change back your visibility too like following code  because [ListView's recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

```
if(j<8){

     holder.text2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     holder.check.setX(-150);

 }else{
     holder.text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     holder.check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
```

and as you have one layout why you Override `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType`?

please remove following line from getView method,

```
 holder.text2.getText();
```

and

```
 Log.v("DDD",  holder.text2.getText().toString());
```

**Your Problem**

your problem is on:

```
private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{           
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position){
         mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        CustomListViewAndroidExample sct = (CustomListViewAndroidExample)activity;
        sct.onItemClick(mPosition);  <--- problem is here
    }               
}
```

I don't know what you want exactly but you can do this.

1- change:

```
 vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
```

to

```
 vi.setOnClickListener(this);
```

2- add following line to getView method:

```
  holder.text.setTag(position);
```

3- add following code to onClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
       TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       int pos = (Integer)tv.getTag();
       Log.d("position of clicked item is", ""+pos);
}
```

4- change

```
if(j<8)
```

to

```
if( position <8)
```

Comment: Sorry that position is by mistake... not using in code...line 222 is public void onClick(View arg0) {
            CustomListViewAndroidExample sct = (CustomListViewAndroidExample)activity;
         sct.onItemClick(mPosition);

Comment: can you update your question because it's hard to read on comment

Comment: why you write `CustomListViewAndroidExample sct = (CustomListViewAndroidExample)activity; sct.onItemClick(mPosition); }`?

Comment: I used http://androidexample.com/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92   this to implement EditText and CheckBox

Comment: link is broken, please fix that, and if you see my answer and use my if else part you don't need `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType` anymore

Comment: Not working ... If i remove getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType  checkbox and edittext behave unexpectedly...on scrolling down

Comment: did you add my if else part?

Comment: did you crash on scroll? or on clicking item?

Comment: on clickin item.. i have updated complete code above please check

Comment: it's must be worked, check one more time, do all 4 thing and check again, if not helped post new code to question instead of existing adapter class

Comment: One last thing...now i have one button on click of that all the value should be stored in the array.. this also gets failed/crashed if i specify the view v=list.getChildAt(i);EditText edit=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText1); after 10 rows in onclicklistener method of button.. for that what should i do

Comment: not is the same, indicate line 89 @ `CustomListViewAndroidExample`

Comment: yes its getting crash with Edittext-->view vListSortOrder=list.getChildAt(i); (89) --> ` EditText edit=(EditText)vListSortOrder. findViewById(R.id.editText1);`

Comment: this question is not related to this tread so first see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209905/how-to-get-values-of-all-edittext-inside-a-listview if you don't get your answer ask another question

Comment: not working.. :(... how do i create collection i posted this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321195/edittext-checkbox-text-value-inside-the-listview

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337254/how-to-get-edittext-text-inside-listview

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Always remember to override these three methods when extending BaseAdapter:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return your_objects_list.size();
}

@Override
public YourObjectType getItem(int position) {

    return your_objects_list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
// you could return any id related to your context, i just return 0 because I don't need it

    return 0;
}
```

### 2. Get rid of these methods:

You definitely do not need these:

---

```
 @Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}


 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position; 
}
```

Look, let me explain when you should be using these methods:

**getViewTypeCount**:

This method should return the number of **different** XML layout files you are using. For example if you are using row_layout_1.xml and row_layout_2.xml files for your rows, your getViewTypeCount() should always return 2.

So if you are using a single .XML file for all the rows, you really shouldn't override this method.

**getItemViewType**:

This method, when called on a single list item, should return the type. In the example I mentioned before, it should return 1 or 2, based on the position of the item.

Since you are using a single XML row type, you shouldn't override this method either.

Let me know your results.

### 3. Don't use `j` at all, use `position` instead.

move this code and **place it one line before return vi**;

```
    if(position <8){
   holder.text2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   holder.check.setX(-150);
   holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }else
    {
         holder.check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         holder.text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

Let me know your results.

Comment: this methods need on `BaseAdapter`, not needed on `ArrayAdapter` class

Comment: No you are wrong. It is definitely needed as ArrayAdapter is an extension of BaseAdapter and he is using some sort of dynamic list with multiple layout types.

Comment: yes, if your class extend `BaseAdapter` class you need those method, but if your class extends `ArrayAdapter` class then super method on constructor handle that

Comment: 1. How do you know he is extending ArrayAdapter?!

2. Even if he is and your assumption is true, he should be overriding getcount to work correctly with multiple layouts.

Comment: I used getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType bcz view was not showing correct on scrolling down the listview...

Comment: i used http://androidexample.com/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92  to use edittext and checkbox inside listview

Comment: @shayanpourvatan: Looks like his reference link is using BaseAdapter and overrides getCount too. I don't know why you disagreed with me without knowing his code.

Comment: @user3226440: My answer is exactly what you need. Work on it and your problem will be solved my friend ;) Ask me if you ran into any problem on the way.

Comment: @Campiador I am doing the same but Not working ... If i remove getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType checkbox and edittext behave unexpectedly...on scrolling down agin checkbox starts 1-7 which should not come

Comment: Aha, now you are on the right track. Did you override the three methods I mentioned in the first part of my answer?

Comment: YEs Tried what you said.. but again.. getting crash from row 11

Comment: @Campiador I'm not disagree with you, but as I don't know OP's code, you don't know that too, i just want to say this method necessary for BaseAdaprer class, that's all.

Comment: @Shayan: No problem, but I had already said that in my answer. And I know he is using BaseAdapter from his source link.

Comment: @user3226440: Can you post your whole adapter code so that I can fix it for you?

Comment: @user3226440 any luck?

Comment: @Campiador thanks for all your help.. I think I am almost there...shayan pourvatan changes working

Comment: Congrats. I would appreciate if you could at least +1 my answer.

Comment: if was going wrong way ..if you can answer me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337254/how-to-get-edittext-text-inside-listview    +1 is not working for me

Comment: +1 should be working for you. I left a comment for that question.